# MySQIi select count and order by count

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

My table looks like this (this is just an example):

```
id    name    title    time
----------------------------
1     name1   title1   1000
2     name1   title1   1001
3     name1   title1   1002
4     name2   title2   1003
5     name2   title2   1004
6     name3   title3   1005
7     name4   title4   1006
8     name4   title4   1007
9     name4   title4   1008
10    name4   title4   1009
```

I want to write a SQL statement to select the count of each name as well as the info related to it. Time is really a UNIX timestamp, but I just changed to make simple for this question.

```
// This is will get me the trending posts for only the last minute
$time_in_past = time() - 60;
$mysqli->query(
    "SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `trending`........WHERE `time` < '$time_in_past'"
);
```

I want to results after fetching with `while()` statement in PHP to be like this:

```
name: name4 count: 4 title: title4
name: name1 count: 3 title: title1
name: name2 count: 2 title: title2
name: name3 count: 1 title: title3
```

I want them to be ordered by COUNT of each one while still getting 10 results (in this example there are only 4).

Comment: I think I'm having difficulty understanding how you want 10 rows to be output, when in your example output you only have four. What should "still getting 10 results" look like?

Comment: this is just an example, I have 100k records entered every minute. So there will be more than 4 outputs. Your sql query only showing 1 result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you could get away with a simple `GROUP BY`, something like this:

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*), title
FROM trending
GROUP BY name, title
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Since your `name` and `title` appear don't ever differ, grouping on those together will not give you any more rows. The ordering by `DESC` give you the count in a reverse order.

Comment: With the input table you have provided, that _should_ show four rows, since I have grouped on two columns that have a variety of values. Can you show us where you are with a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? If you can do that, edit it into your question as well as pinging me, so everyone can see the update.

Comment: @Max: thanks for the update on your question, a Fiddle would be the best next step!

Answer (score 4):

You need to group your results (by name), then join the result to your table again:

```sql
SELECT * FROM trending NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   name, COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM     trending
  WHERE    time < ?
  GROUP BY name
) t
WHERE    time < ?
ORDER BY t.cnt DESC
```